# Can't retrieve object property in view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have an object called doctors, and I want to retrieve its properties, e.g., name, specialty, city, but it keeps giving me an error. [like this](https://i.ibb.co/Z21PT0P/Screenshot-20190414-001309.png)

If I explicitly pass in the object, it gives me the JSON formatted result[image: like this]

**view.blade.php**

```php
<ul> 
    @foreach($doctors as $d)
    <li>
       {{ $d->name }}
       {{ $d->specialty->name }}
       {{ $d->city->name }}
    </li> 
    @endforeach 
</ul>
```

If I do it like this:

```php
{{ $doctors }}
```

It gives me the JSON result as I mentioned before. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Most likely you have to use https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: @shock_gone_wild the problem is, this isn't my only object and view, i also have article object which i also retrieve its properties to a view, but it didn't give me any errors, it works the way i wanted

Comment: try it like this:  @foreach(json_decode($doctors) as $d)   Obviously $doctors is a Json Encoded String

Comment: If you call `$d->specialty->name` or `$d->city->name` you also need the objects in your json string. But this is not the case. Yes, there is a `name` object but not inside a `city` or `speciality` object. Instead I can see `speciality_id` and `city_id` objects which probably stand in correlation with another table in your database. But to retrieve them you have to do another query of course.

Comment: @Aaron3219 the doctors object model is already related to specialty and city

Comment: Doesn't matter. If it isn't in your json object you can't loop through it.

Comment: yes. solutions are in the controller, not in the view blade. eager load those relationships. and return response without json.

Comment: Could you provide the code inside the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like.. ?

`<ul> 
    @foreach($doctors as $d)
    <li>
       {{ $d['name'] }}
    </li> 
    @endforeach 
</ul>`